# PHP error on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, php

I want to install CodeIgniter 4, but this error stops the installation.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'intl' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/intl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.4.7 (cli) (built: Jun 12 2020 07:43:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json composer
```

In the folder above your project root:

```
composer create-project codeigniter4/appstarter project-root
```

The command above will create a *project-root* folder.

Whenever there is a new release, then from the terminal in your project root:

```
composer update
```